# dc.js / crossfilter SeriesChart top 5 lines

Tags: crossfilter, dc

Hello i have a question i have a SeriesChart, and it works fine, but i would like to limit the count of lines and sum the other into one line.

Like the pieChart or RowCharts

What is the best way for doing this?

```
var group = BIData.ndx.dimension(function (d) { return  [d['CUSTOMER'], d3.timeMonth(d['DATE'])];
```